# How is construct function working even when variable is assigned null value?

Tags: plugin-development, oop

I'm unable to understand the function of __construct here. I know that in any class __construct runs anytime the class is instantiated. However, my curiosity is, when $marks is defined as null in the __construct function, then why it is checking for its value in the if statement of __construct? Won't it always return false?

```
class Marks_Manage
{
    public $mark_id;
    public $exam_id;
    public $class_id;
    public $subject_id;
    public $marks;
    public $attendance;
    public $student_id;
    public $marks_comment;
    public $created_date;
    //current_time( 'mysql' );

    public function __construct( $marks = null ) 
    {
        if($marks)
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "marks";
            $mark_data = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE mark_id=".$marks);
            $this->mark_id = $mark_data->mark_id;
            $this->exam_id = $mark_data->exam_id;
            $this->class_id = $mark_data->class_id;
            $this->subject_id = $mark_data->subject_id;
            $this->marks = $mark_data->marks;
            $this->attendance = $mark_data->attendance;
            $this->student_id = $mark_data->student_id;
            $this->marks_comment = $mark_data->marks_comment;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to pass variables to class constructs.

```
$blarg = new Marks_Manage( 'string' );
```

Now the conditional `if( $marks )` returns true.

If nothing is passed to the class construct:

```
$blarg = new Marks_Manage();
```

Then `$marks` would be null and `if( $marks )` evaluate as false;

Comment: But arent' we already setting the value of variable $marks to be null by defining it in class construct?

Comment: Only if nothing is passed to the class constructor.